# JS -how to return & rerun a function?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, call

I have a onButtonClick function,
 when a certain condition is met I'd like to return the result (update the browser),
and rerun the function.

*...The reason I'm doing this is that changing a transformation property, if I don't reset at a certain degree the rotation won't be coherent...*

Here's what my click called function looks like:

```
var degree=0,
     axis='Y';

 function onButtonClick(e) {

     var x = this.className.slice(5);


        if (condition === true){
//needs to update browser
           box.style.transform = "translateZ(-"+trans+"px) rotateY(-180deg)";
//now I need to return & rerun this whole function (possibly repeating the call)  
        };


       /* switches and manipulations */


   box.style.transform = "translateZ(-"+ trans +"px) rotate"+ axis +"("+ degree +"deg)";

}
```

With this code, if the specific condition is met it's not updated in the browser, so when the transformation takes place calculation isn't modified.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: sorry if it isn't clear, the question is how to return something and automatically call function again ?

Comment: try to use `setTimeout(onButtonClick, 0);` to redraw and rerun function

Comment: @maioman And this click is the only event that changes the "condition" you are talking about?

Comment: @activatedGeek yes, It needs to change only if it goes in a certain direction and you can only tell direction on click